# how to count google ad clicks with google analytics big query table

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to count the correct number of google ad clicks in the google analytics big query table, but the numbers differ when compared with the google analytics web interface.

I tried two different approaches, counting only the entrance hits of each visit and group by channelGrouping:

```
  SELECT 
    channelGrouping,
    count(*) as clicks,
  FROM `ga_sessions_table`, UNNEST(hits) as hits
  WHERE hits.isEntrance
  GROUP BY channelGrouping
```

Or counting each PAGE event

```
  SELECT 
    channelGrouping,
    count(*) as clicks,
  FROM `ga_sessions_table`, UNNEST(hits) as hits
  WHERE hits.type = 'PAGE'
  GROUP BY channelGrouping
```

I compare one specific day in our data.

With the first query I get around 10% less of clicks as in the web UI.

With the second query I get more than 3 times more compare to the web UI.

How do I correctly count the clicks with that table?

Comment: Check this out, here Jimmy Pang is doing similar things : https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-handle-google-analytics-data-in-bigquery-f4307062eada

Comment: @narendra thanks for the tip. But that page does not provide an answer to my question.